# jQuery check if target is link

Tags: javascript, click

I have a global function to capture clicks.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  //do something
  if(clickedOnLink)
    //do something
});
```

I want to do additional stuff when the target is a link, but if the the `<a>` tag actually surrounds a div (as HTML5 allows this) the target will be that div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Af37v/

Comment: When you say 'target' do you mean the element with an `id` that receives focus, so would match the `:target` pseudo-selector, or the element that was clicked to trigger the navigation?

Comment: I actually want to `do something else` if the user will be redirected to another page by clicking on a href.

Comment: I don't think it's valid HTML to have a `<div>` inside an `<a>`

Comment: It is in HTML5. `<a>` can wrap around block elements. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes

Comment: @Cristy: Ok, I wasn't sure.

Comment: But if you place the click-handler on the `a` element (`$('a')`) then it'll tell you it's a link, because the `click` bubbles up through the document.

Comment: Yeah but that won't result in DRY coding as I had to repeat the first `do something` in the $('a').click() function.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try to see if the element you clicked on either is or is a child of an `<a>` tag.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('a').length){
        alert('You clicked a link');
    }
    else{
        alert('You did not click a link');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 21):

I believe using `is` will actually have better performance than the answers suggesting `closest`:

```
$(e.target).is('a, a *');
```

This checks if the element itself is an `a` or if it is contained with an `a`.

This should be faster than `closest` because it will use [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) on the element itself and not need to traverse up the DOM tree as `closest` will do.

Comment: Why do you think it's faster this way? What exactly does `.is('a *')` do ?

Comment: @cristy `is` should just use [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) in supporting browsers.  That is a single call for just the element instead of parsing up the dom checking each element.  I'll create a jsperf and update the answer.

Comment: can't seem to get jsperf to let me add more test cases but you can see the test for a matching nested element:  https://jsperf.com/a-or-in-a  I suspect the gap should widen for deeply nested element, particularly those that are not nested within an `a`.

Comment: That is cool, what about browser suport? Does this work in all browsers?

Comment: @Cristy thanks to jquery it should work in any browser.  You may not see a wide gap in performance on really old browsers though that don't support `matches`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  //do something
  if($(this).closest('a').length)
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If the exact target is link, then you can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Example:

```
$(".element").on("click", function(e){
  if($(e.target).is("a")){
    //do your stuff
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

If it is surrounded by other element that is inside an anchor tag, then you can use `closest()` and check whether it have anchor tag parent or not by using `length`

Example:

```
$(".element").on("click", function(e){
  if($(e.target).closest("a").length){
    //do your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: As other I said in my answer, it is not enough to check if the target is a link. It could be **inside** an `a` tag.

Comment: Yeah that is correct, but it is exactly the same as the accepted answer. Polluting the page with duplicate answers is never a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

With jquery just get the tagName attribute
$("a").prop("tagName");

Comment: And how does this help me to actually check if the click will result in a redirect or not?

Comment: $("a").prop("tagName") == 'a' and then check if that 'a' contains a div

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
You could check if the target is an a or if a parent is an a.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.closest('a').length > 0) {
            alert('i am an a');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8jeGV/4/

Comment: If `$target` *is* an `<a>`, then `.closest` will return it.  So you only need `$target.closest('a').length > 0`, you don't need to check `.is`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if there's a `<div>` under `<a>` by testing if the [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) `<div>` has anything inside it. If nothing is inside, or there is no `<div>`, the `if` statement will return `false`.

I suggest this code:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var willRedirect = ($('a[href="/"]').attr('href').indexOf('#') == -1 ? true : false),

    //run code

    if ( willRedirect === false ){
        e.preventDefault();

        //the link will not redirect

        if ( $(this).children('div').html() ){
            //there is a <div> inside <a> containing something
        }
        else {
            //there is no <div> inside <a>
        }
    }
    else {
        //the link is not pointing to your site
    }
});
```