# jQuery - check if target is specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
$(".closebox").click(function(){
    $('#uploadbox').hide();
    $('#lightbox').hide();
    $('#deniedbox').hide();
    $('#confirm_delete_box').hide();
}).children().click(function(e) {

console.log(e.target.id); // I get "previewHolder" and "filePhoto" in the console 

    if($(e.target).is('#previewHolder')){
        console.log('yes');
        return false;
    }else{
        console.log('nope');
        return false;
    }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="uploadbox">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="height: 100%;" class="closebox">
            <div style="background-color: white; border-radius: 8px; padding-top: 12px; display: inline-block; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1); box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);">


                <div style="margin: 20px; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; line-height: 6px; max-height: 800px; overflow: auto;" id="upbox">

                    <input type="file" name="filePhoto" value="" id="filePhoto" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" data-errormsg="Something went wrong" style="display: none;">

                    <div id="upload_title_afterview" style="font-size: 22px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 6px; color: #404040; text-align: left; max-width: 500px; line-height: 26px; display: none;"></div>                  

                    <img src="<?php echo $domain; ?>/style/upload_background.jpg" id="previewHolder" style="max-width: 498px; max-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; border: solid 1px #C0C0C0; cursor: pointer;" onclick="choose_image();"/>
                    <br>

                    <div id="upload_error" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; color: #FF6600; font-size: 18px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; display: none;">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

I got this from [jQuery check if target is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327489/jquery-check-if-target-is-link), before somebody mark this as duplicate, none of those solutions are working in my specific case.

I need to find out wheather `#previewHolder` was clicked and with this code both conditions are true, so I get `nope` and `yes` in the console. I guess because `.closebox` has multiple children. How can I solve this?

This is the whole idea:
When the user clicks on .closebox then I want all the divs to be hidden except he clicks on a child element, but then I want a function to be triggered when the child element is #previewHolder

Comment: Can you show the HTML you are working with as well?

Comment: Also, why would the event.target be that string? Maybe look to see if the event target ```id``` matches that string. Also ```$(e.target)``` has me confused. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Yes #previewHolder is inside .closebox, I added the HTML to the question

Comment: why you are using Id if you having multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

```
click(function(e){
    if($("#previewHolder").is(e.target)){
         console.log("yes");
    }
    else {
         console.log("nop");
    }
});
```

The `"#previewHolder"` is only a string.

Comment: This way both conditions are also true

Comment: @EduardUnruh I think there is more than one object under the div you'd better find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it so that `.closebox` doesn't close when clicking `#previewHolder` you simply need to do the following:

```
$('#previewHolder').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //add any code you want here
});
```

The code `e.stopPropagation();` stops the `.closebox` event from triggering

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're after, can you try explaining it a different way?

Comment: When the user clicks on .closebox then I want all the divs to be hidden except he clicks on a child element, but then I want a function to be triggered when the child element is #previewHolder and still keep all the divs from being closed

Answer (score 0):

Please go thorough the below code and see if this is what you want. Click on each child element and see the behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".childbox").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")=="previewHolder"){
       previewHolderClick()
    }
    else{
       $(".childbox").hide();
       $(this).show();
    }
 });
 
 function previewHolderClick(){
  alert("previewHolder clicked");
 }
 
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="closebox" style="width:200px; height:200px; background:yellow">
  <div class="childbox">Child 1</div><br>
  <div class="childbox">Child 2</div><br>
  <div class="childbox" id="previewHolder">previewHolder<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No that's not what I need, please check the answer I made to FirstLegion